# How do I set Kraken.js generator options

Tags: javascript, node.js, kraken.js

Im trying to find a way to generate a Kraken.js project that uses jade instead of dust templates. According to [their documentation](https://github.com/krakenjs/generator-kraken#generators) you should be able to pass the template engine as a parameter, so `yo kraken --templateModule=consolidate` should generate a jade based project, however the parameter seems to have no effect on the generation of the project.

Am I maybe setting the parameters wrong or using the wrong name for jade. Unfortunately Googling the problem has not turned up anything useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`yo kraken --templateModule=consolidate` shouldn't work and it doesn't work as it throw error:
`throw new Error('Unable to resolve dependency: ' + key + ':' + val`

Please take a look into `dependencies.js`

```
module.exports = {

    dustjs: {
        bower: [
            'dustjs-linkedin#^2.0.3',
            'dustjs-linkedin-helpers#^1.1.1'
        ],
        npm: [
            'dustjs-linkedin@^2.0.3',
            'dustjs-helpers@^1.1.1',
            'adaro@^0.1.5'
        ],
        npmDev: [
            'grunt-dustjs@^1.2.0'
        ]
    },
}
```

Then you must study `index.js`

```
this._addDependency('templateModule', options.templateModule);

proto._addDependency = function addDependency(key, value) {
    this[key] = value;

    if (value) {
        if (dependencies[value]) {
            this.dependencies.push(value);
        } else {
            throw new Error('Unable to resolve dependency: ' + key + ':' + value);
        }
    }
};
```

If you pass value that can't be find in `dependencies.js` if will throw an error

Comment: Ok , so pretty much the only way this is happening is if support is added